# Função apply, extrair dados da regressão

Tags: r, apply, lm

Tenho a seguinte amostra:

```
x <- structure(list(POP = structure(c(1L, 12L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 
14L), .Label = c("pop1", "pop10", "pop11", "pop12", "pop13", 
"pop14", "pop15", "pop16", "pop17", "pop18", "pop19", "pop2", 
"pop20", "pop21", "pop3", "pop4", "pop5", "pop6", "pop7", "pop8", 
"pop9"), class = "factor"), a1 = c(91, 26.7, 51.9, 14, 0, 15.3, 
34.4, 19.1, 10.2, 52.5, 43.6, 13.1, 47.1, 34.7, 0, 58.9, 66.8, 
0, 0, 0, 0), a2 = c(92.9, 27.7, 54.1, 14.3, 0, 16.2, 35, 19.1, 
11.1, 52.5, 44.6, 13.4, 48.7, 34.4, 0, 59.5, 72.3, 0, 0, 0, 0
), a3 = c(92.6, 27.4, 54.7, 13.7, 0, 16.2, 36, 0, 11.1, 53.2, 
45.2, 13.7, 49.3, 0, 0, 59.5, 74.5, 0, 0, 0, 0), a4 = c(95.5, 
28.3, 57.3, 14.6, 0, 16.9, 36.9, 0, 11.8, 56.3, 47.1, 14, 53.2, 
0, 0, 62.7, 84.4, 0, 0, 0, 0), a5 = c(97.4, 28.6, 61.4, 14.3, 
0, 17.5, 36.9, 0, 12.4, 55.7, 47.4, 14.6, 53.8, 0, 0, 62.4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), a6 = c(97.7, 29.3, 63.3, 14.6, 0, 18.5, 38.8, 0, 
13.1, 57.3, 49, 15.3, 55.4, 0, 0, 62.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), a7 = c(102.2, 
0, 68.1, 14.6, 11.1, 20.1, 43.3, 0, 14.6, 64.9, 53.2, 0, 60.5, 
0, 0, 62.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), a8 = c(106.3, 0, 71.9, 14.3, 0, 19.7, 
45.8, 0, 15.9, 70.7, 57.3, 0, 67.8, 0, 10.5, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 
0), a9 = c(113.2, 0, 75.5, 15, 0, 21.7, 49, 0, 18.5, 73, 59.8, 
0, 0, 0, 14.7, 0, 0, 0, 10.4, 0, 0), a10 = c(114.9, 0, 75.2, 
15, 0, 22.6, 49.6, 0, 19.8, 73.8, 59.9, 0, 0, 0, 16.6, 0, 0, 
10.5, 10.5, 0, 0), a11 = c(114.9, 0, 75.5, 15.1, 0, 23.2, 50.6, 
0, 19.8, 74.6, 59.2, 0, 0, 0, 18.2, 0, 0, 10.5, 10.6, 0, 0), 
    a12 = c(115, 0, 76, 15.9, 0, 26.1, 0, 0, 22.7, 75.4, 60.8, 
    0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 10.3, 11.1, 0, 0), a13 = c(115.2, 11.6, 
    76, 16, 0, 26.6, 0, 0, 23.3, 75.5, 61.3, 0, 0, 0, 22.6, 0, 
    0, 10.7, 11.1, 0, 0), a14 = c(0, 11.6, 77.6, 0, 0, 29.5, 
    0, 0, 25.3, 76.2, 64, 0, 0, 0, 25.5, 0, 0, 11.6, 11.8, 10.2, 
    11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

E os dados anuais:

```
temp <- structure(list(ano = structure(c(1L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("a1", "a10", "a11", 
"a12", "a13", "a14", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", 
"a9"), class = "factor"), temp = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 13L, 
8L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Aqui eu crio listas para receber os valores de interpolação, que será feito por um loop (for)

```
model_list <- list()
x_list <- list()
y_list <- list()
y <- temp$temp

log_x <- apply(x[-1], 2, log)
```

E elimino as linhas que não tem nenhuma observação válida

```
# linhas em log_x com -Inf em todas as lacunas
 linhas <- c(3,6,9,10,11)
 # Linhas com Algum Valor (LAV) 
 lav <- (1:21)[-linhas]
 lav
 # [1]  1  2  4  5  7  8 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Agora eu crio um loop que i) remove as posições sem observação, tanto no arquivo log_x como no y também; ii) Faz as interpolações.
Também uso uma função `if` `else` para colocar `NA` nas observações que tiveram o comprimento menor que 3

```
for(i in (lav)){ # loop por linha
  # indices de coluna com valores -Inf
  indice_com_inf <- which(log_x[i,]<0)
  # criar lista de x sem os -inf
  x_list[[i]] <- log_x[i,-indice_com_inf]
  # novo y1 em lista, sem os indices de valores -Inf
  y_list[[i]] <- y[-indice_com_inf]
  # condição
  if (length(x_list[[i]]) >= 3) { #condição comprimento >=3
    #rodar regressão
    model_list[[i]] <- lm(x_list[[i]] ~ y_list[[i]])
  } else {
    model_list[[i]] <- NA #se não atender a condição, não fazer nada
  }}
```

Depois disso gostaria de extrair os dados com uma função `apply`
da seguinte forma:

```
coef_list <- t(sapply(model_list, coef))

model_smry <- lapply(model_list, summary)

R2_list <- sapply(model_smry, '[[', 'r.squared')
pval_list <- t(sapply(model_smry, function(LM){
  LM[['coefficients']][, 4]
}))

f_list <- t(sapply(model_smry, '[[', 'fstatistic'))
```

Mas obtenho o erro `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`
eu entendo que seja o valor `NA`, como posso fazer para extrair os dados, e gostaria que os valores `NA` não fossem retirados, pois eu preciso deles para inserir o nome das observações na ordem e no `length` da amostra.

como fazer esse processo agora?
tem como as observações que não foram calculadas as regressões, ficarem com um valor `zero` e ir seguindo, linha por linha, extraindo os dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que sua lista `model_list` tem elementos do tipo `list`, que são o resultado de `lm`, elementos tipo NULL, onde o `if` não fez nada, e elementos tipo NA, onde ela passou para o `else`.
Uma opção seria você mudar como você criou essa lista, para evitar isso. Aí você usa `model_list_novo` nos `sapply`.

```
model_list_novo <- model_list[lengths(model_list)>1]
```

Mas como você pode achar importante saber as posições em que não foram calculados os coeficientes, você pode testar dentro do apply para só os elementos que vierem do lm sofrerem alguma operação:

```
coef_list <- t(sapply(model_list, function(M){
    if(is.list(M)) coef(M)
}))

R2_list <- sapply(model_smry, function(M){
    if(is.list(M) > 3) M[['r.squared']]
})

pval_list <- t(sapply(model_smry, function(LM){
    if(length(LM)>3) LM[['coefficients']][, 4]
}))

f_list <- sapply(model_smry, function(M){
    if(length(M) > 3) M[['fstatistic']]
})
```

Pra cada `apply` teria que ter um `if` assim.